# How to parse Facebook feed and display on website

Tags: php, facebook

I am looking for a way to display the latest few posts from a Facebook page on a website page. I've gone through the process of creating an Ap and getting the access tokens, etc. Now they want to do an App review which takes 5 days.

My question is, in 2020 is there a simple way to do this? I don't want to use the FB embed option, rather I'd like to use php to parse an RSS feed so that I could simply display the latest few entries.

I've spent several hours trying to figure this out and can't seem to find any examples. Is what I'm trying to do purposely made difficult to shy people away from doing this?

Any help would be great! Im using the php-graph-sdk and this is my code

```
try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '/id/feed','token'
  );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

But I get this error
**Graph returned an error: (#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_user_content' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature**

Comment: based on the error, you need to get "read_user_content" permission for your app to get access to the feed.

Comment: So how come this site can fetch the feed without me enabling anything? https://fetchrss.com/facebook

Comment: Because the site has successfully applied as a developer on Facebook and Facebook has granted their request.  You will have to apply like I did on Twitter and they will or will not grant it. I was denied by Facebook a few times.

Comment: that makes sense now